# Is there a way to access the Google Docs Summary from Apps Script?

Tags: google-docs-api

In March 2022, Google announced [autogenerated summaries for some documents](http://ai.googleblog.com/2022/03/auto-generated-summaries-in-google-docs.html), alongside the document outline. I'm wondering if there's a way to access these summaries in gas, e.g. via [DocumentApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document-app).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Get summary text from Google Document:

In the current stage, in order to retrieve the document summary, you can retrieve it using Drive API as follows.

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/fileId?fields=description
```

The sample Google Apps Script is as follows. When you use this, please enable Drive API at Advanced Google services.

```js
const documentId = "###"; // Please set Document ID.
const summary = Drive.Files.get(documentId).description;
console.log(summary)
```

- When this script is run, the summary text of Google Document can be retrieved.
- In this case, you can also use Drive service (DriveApp) as follows.

  ```
    const documentId = "###"; // Please set Document ID.
    const summary = DriveApp.getFileById(documentId).getDescription();
    console.log(summary)
  ```

#### Set summary text to Google Document:

In order to retrieve the document summary, you can put it using Drive API as follows.

```
PATCH https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/fileId

content-type: application/json

{"description": "sample summary text"}
```

The sample Google Apps Script is as follows. When you use this, please enable Drive API at Advanced Google services.

```js
const documentId = "###"; // Please set Document ID.
const summary = "sample summary";
Drive.Files.patch({description: summary}, documentId);
```

- When this script is run, the summary text can be put to Google Document.
- In this case, you can also use Drive service (DriveApp) as follows.

  ```
    const documentId = "###"; // Please set Document ID.
    const summary = "sample summary";
    DriveApp.getFileById(documentId).setDescription(summary);
  ```

#### Note:

- Unfortunately, in the current stage, I cannot test these scripts for the autogenerated summary in Document. But, I guess that the autogenerated summary might be able to be retrieved by this method.

#### References:

- [Files: get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get)
- [Files: update](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/update)
- [getDescription()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getdescription)
- [setDescription(description)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#setdescriptiondescription)

Comment: I was wrong on my answer, therefore I have deleted it. This answer is correct if you want to get the summary of the file. Also, if the answer does not work for the AI generated summaries, you can open a feature request on Issue Tracker.

Comment: @Kessy Thank you for your comment. I agree with your comment. Although I cannot still test the autogenerated summary in Document, when the autogenerated summary cannot be directly retrieved using Drive API, I also think that it should be reported to the issue tracker as a future request.